# static protected resource shared through inheritance

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance

In an attempt to replace the singleton pattern and a general "Resource Manager", I came with a solution. Making a resource static and protected. That resource is shared between all children from the inherited class. It works, but I wasn't sure if it's a good way to proceed.
Here's a bit of code to express what I'm doing(the resource here is the sf::Texture):

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        if(m_texture == nullptr) {
            //Création et chargement de la texture
            m_texture = std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture>(new sf::Texture());
            m_texture->loadFromFile("...");
        }

    }

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) = 0;

protected:
    static std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> m_texture = nullptr;

};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    Bar()
        : m_sprite(*m_texture) {}

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
        window.draw(m_sprite); 
    }

private:
    sf::Sprite m_sprite;
};
```

That way my resources is shared through all children, and is only initialized once.
Is it a good solution to replace a singleton or a Resource Manager that I would carry everywhere through reference.
Thank you!

Comment: I like the Idea myself, and was Googling to see if you get my suspected performance gain. Every time I see a pattern I see an indirection cost. This seems to be a way to clear the stink of singletons.<br/>This puts the class metadata where it belongs, inside the class. I would go further and say that if you are looking for performance and flexibility of object creation it is a good design to do this with the other patterns as well, adding alternative factories as static functions in order to support other patterns with different interfaces.<br/>What benefits are gained through externalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally what you are tying to do is correct, a static member will be shared (ie be exactly the same) among all the inherited class, this way you only need a single instance which can save you a ton of memory but heres a couple issues ... Im assuming you are using g++.

You can't initialize non-const member within a class declaration so this.
`static std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> m_texture = nullptr;`
would produce this: 
**error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member**
you have to initialize it within the source file of your class, but outside the class.
`std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> Foo::m_texture = nullptr;`

Second it isn't save to access member fields directly, always use setters and getters, even within the class functions, this makes the code much more maintainable. As such you can have a static function called getTexture

```
static std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> getTexture() {
    if(m_texture == nullptr) {
        //Création et chargement de la texture
        m_texture = std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture>(new sf::Texture());
        m_texture->loadFromFile("...");
    }
    return m_texture;
}
```

while its true that the if statement and function call do add come overhead, this is much more maintainable and safer, and it load the texture at the last minute when its truly needed.

Back to your question, the Singleton design pattern is quite simple and mostly used to save memory since only a single instance of the object is ever created :) Resource managers are a whole different beast their goal is to centralize all the actions that are required loading and managing resources, combining the two you would initialize a single instance of a resource manager, then access it though a static member field, having all the objects make requests for resources, this could be good or bad, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Software design is hard. The best advice I can give is this, when designing a system ask yourself this, "how many lines of code would I have to write to introduce another similar component" your goal should be to minimize this as much as possible, ie reuse as much as possible what you have already created.

The best programmers are the laziest :) and no I don't mean copy/paste, that should be banned.

Comment: For your first point, I am aware of that, and I use VS2010. It was to simplified, but I initialize the pointer like you do outside.
For your second point, makes sense, thank you.
Third, I didn't want to do a singleton since it's pretty much a global and I dislike those.
Finaly, I am doing all this to learn and get good notion so I can get better. I wanted to explore other alternative to singleton and resource manager in this context. Also, I hate Copy/paste as I don't learn anything.

Comment: THANK YOU! I wish more programmers would think like you! The singleton design pattern is ok if you have a small number of objects but it gets really really hard to manage them once the number of objects increases, this is why its rarely used on its own, a lot times we borrow ideas from different designs to implement our systems... If you always access your members through setters/getters its ok even on a global scope :)

Comment: also look into cohesion and coupling.

Answer (score 0):

The design looks suspicious. I don't see any advantage of using this over the more widely used Singleton pattern (with a function local static instance). You're probably best off initializing the `m_texture` object with a default `Texture` at the point of definition (and not within `Foo`'s ctor):

```
static std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> m_texture( new sf::Texture() );
```

Data members are ideally suited for derived classes. Base classes are typically to define interfaces.

I'd suggest that you keep your resource manager class (`Foo`) separate and instead of inheriting from it, call appropriate member functions to get to the `Texture` object.

Comment: The fact that it's static makes that I only get one initialisation of the object, and only in the case it's value is nullptr. It works, you could try to put a `std::cout<<"Init";` inside the if statement, and it would only appear once, even when creating two `Bar` objects.

Comment: Ah. Yes. My bad. I missed the `if` test. Anyway, this still doesn't look like a good way to implement. Data members are ideally suited for derived classes. Base classes are typically to define interfaces. I suggest you take a look at the handle-body/pimpl idiom.

Comment: That's exactly why I asked. It works well, but I really wasn't sure of the way. Going to take a look at the idiom. Thank you.